# php array to string conversion odbc_exec count

Tags: php, sql-server

i'm still new towards php but after searching through multiple topics i can't seem to figure this one out.

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(MAP_CODE2) FROM TCODE_MAPPING WHERE MAP_CODE2 = 'ABC123'";
$result2 = odbc_exec($connect,$query2);
echo $result2;
```

i have a query above that i'd like to use to get the total number of rows within the query that i've set, however for some reason i keep getting hit by the error

> Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/xxx.php on line 85

Would highly appreciate if anyone could help out on what i'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: you are trying to `echo` a result-set object of array type. use `odbc_fetch_row()` for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it looks like i've been using the wrong command for this then. i've tried with the odbc_fetch_row() and this gave me exactly what i wanted. 

Thank you once more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem is:-***

You are trying to `echo` a result-set object of `array` type.

***Solution (check the code comments):-***

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(MAP_CODE2) AS MYCOUNT FROM TCODE_MAPPING WHERE MAP_CODE2 = 'ABC123'"; // given a name to the count

$result2 = odbc_exec($connect,$query2); //prepare and execute query

while (odbc_fetch_row($result2)) { //iterate over result-set object

  echo odbc_result($result, "MYCOUNT"), "\n"; // echo count

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is you are echoing an array object type that is also a resource type and php `echo` only string and other primitive type variables.

so you need to use a loop to access the row or to get row count and access row just use a `foreach($results as $result)`

to get row count visit this [sqlsrv-num-rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) . on this official php link you can get more example how to fetch data.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Alive to Die has given me the exact solution of why i couldn't get it to work though the information you've given is useful as well.